# Crafter CMS: retrieving data from a different page/content-type

Tags: freemarker, crafter-cms

Is it possible to retrieve data from a separate page? I only know how to use `contentModel.VARIABLENAME` in my ftl templates.

For example, I am currently in **Page A** but the data I want to display is from **Page B**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `siteItemService`:

```
<#assign pageB = siteItemService.getSiteItem("/site/website/path/to/pageB/index.xml") />
```

You just need to replace `path/to/pageB` for the page path as shown in the Sidebar. The object returned is of the exact same type as `contentModel`, so you can do `siteItemService.VARIABLENAME`